# How to Best Grant Full Guest Access To A Microsoft Teams Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Federico is an external user from another company that needs access to SharePoint resources on our company side, *mycompany.com*. I'd rather have him access our resources via Microsoft Teams on the web because that's the user experience I want to give him. However, though I grant him *guest* access using his Erik@hiscompany external e-mail address, both the SharePoint web interface and Teams will request he logs in using a password.

We had a similar situation with Myrtle as well in the past. She's another external contractor. I tried allowing her in as,

- Her original Myrtle@hercompany.com email--but since this understandably has no credentials within our domain and thus no password, she couldn't get in at the login prompt
- A new, personal Myrtle@outlook.com address we created for her uniquely for this purpose so she could actually have a password to login with as it seemed SharePoint/Teams does allow a *Microsoft* email address to login via the credentials prompt
- A company-assigned Myrtle@mycompany.com username/password I gave her within our domain

Ultimately, after trying unsuccessfully to grant her access to the files she needed with the first two methods, we ended up giving Myrtle a *mycompany.com* login (the last email address assigned to her, per the above). That worked, but didn't fully satisfy me as now it might seem as though she's employed by us--which she is not.

Federico’s trouble accessing our resources now might be similarly best resolved by granting him the same--a mycompany.com address within our domain. But **is this truly my best and only option?**

I know I gave Myrtle an Exchange mailbox with a mycompany.com email address, so that she can use our calendars, browse our Teams folder structure, etc. I set up a contact for her in my ActiveDirectory with what amounts to a dummy internal address and her personal external mail address. All this worked. I suppose I could likewise create and set Federico's dummy internal e-mail account to forward to his @hiscompany.com address also, and then just hide his dummy contact from the GAL afterwards.

Is this what others recommend as well?

Answer (score 0):

The below article should get you started.  Because Teams consumes resources from different O365 "systems" you need to enable external access in a few different places for external users to have full access in Teams.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-dependencies